# ASP.net csv download removes newlines

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to provide a csv file generated by the server for download by url. The problem is the resulting csv file loses newline symbols. All the data appears on one row (single line), and that is not what I need. Original file is fine, has all lines correctly. a I'm on .Net Framework 4.7.1.

Here's example code:

```
public async Task<FileResult> Download()
        {
            string filepath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + $"filename.csv";
            if (!System.IO.File.Exists(filepath))
                System.IO.File.WriteAllText(filepath, "");


            return File(filepath, "text/csv", $"filename.csv");
        }
```

I have tried multiple things, providing filestream, byte array, but all of that results in the same thing. How can I fix that?

Comment: What tool are you using to open the file?  Microsoft last year changed the default return to be compatible with Linux.  It is not your code.  You code is not modifying the return character.  I started seeing same issue with Notepad a couple of years ago.  You can change Notepad option for return chanacter.

Comment: I used multiple different tools to open the downloaded file, I tried excel, googlesheets, https://www.convertcsv.com/csv-viewer-editor.htm , I even checked in VS Code, there is literally one single line. Original file is correct in all of these tools.

Comment: Try File.WriteAllLines instead of File.WriteAllText

Comment: That is just to make function provide an empty file, in case when csv file hasn't been generated yet.

Comment: Does file have the returns before you download?  What OS/Tool are you using to view the file before downloading.  Did you try with notepadd++.  Notepad++ has an option to see the returns under View : Symbols.

Comment: File is generated on the server and is stored on the server. I need to make it available for download. When I do that, I get a file without newline symbols. I checked with notepad++, original file is good, downloaded file has no newline symbols.

Comment: Then sorry mate. I never had a problem like this. There must be some missing pieces that you forgot to mention. You need to provide code that fills the csv file. Downloading file does not change the contents. There is something wrong with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I create my CSV content:

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
var dataSeparator = ";";
var lineTemplate = $"{satirbasligi}{satirverisi}{scrapAddition}";
stringBuilder.Append(lineTemplate.TrimEnd(dataSeparator.ToCharArray()));
stringBuilder.AppendLine();
var csvString = stringBuilder.ToString();
```

P.S.: Please note that this not the whole code but just part of it. It needs some collection or some array to iterate on it to create lines.

You need to use **AppendLine** at the end of each row when creating the CSV content.

Edit to original answer:

This is how i return my file. Maybe this helps

```
this.Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
this.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", $"attachment; filename={reportFileName}");
return File(new System.Text.UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(csvString), "text/csv", reportFileName);
```

By the way, I am not creating file in the file system just returning it as a file response to the user.

Comment: File that I generate is fine. When I generate it I do use AppendLine, and it has all the lines correctly. The problem is when I download file from my server, it comes out without newline symbols at all.

Comment: @Reconder added details about returning csv file.

Comment: I have tried that, but it didn't help.

Comment: Then sorry mate. I never had a problem like this. There must be some missing pieces that you forgot to mention. You need to provide code that fills the csv file.

Answer (score -1):

The issue you're experiencing with newline symbols in your CSV file might be related to how line endings are handled in different environments (e.g., Windows, Unix). To ensure that the downloaded CSV file retains proper line endings, you can specify the encoding when writing the file. You should use the `StreamWriter` class and specify the encoding as follows:

```cs
public async Task<FileResult> Download()
{
    string filepath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + $"filename.csv";

    if (!System.IO.File.Exists(filepath))
    {
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filepath, false, Encoding.UTF8)) // Specify the desired encoding (UTF-8)
        {
            // Write your CSV data to the file using StreamWriter
            // Example: writer.WriteLine("Column1,Column2,Column3");
        }
    }

    return File(filepath, "text/csv", $"filename.csv");
}
```

By using `StreamWriter` with the UTF-8 encoding (or the encoding that matches your requirements), you should ensure that the line endings are correctly handled, and your downloaded CSV file will have the expected line breaks.